# Option key boot selector suddenly failing

Tags: macos, dual-boot

I have an early 2008 Mac Pro (12 GB, several hard disks).  On OS X I run Yosemtite, On Bootcamp, Windows 7.  All works fine.  Yesterday I installed a "new" Radeon 5770 to replace the aged (and very slow) Radeon 2600 that came with the system.  Installation was easy and the system came up perfectly.  The one weird glitch is that pressing the Option key during boot up no longer works.  Worked before but not now. Id I do press Option during boot (before or after the chime) the system just hangs and it never comes up.  I have to turn the system off and back on. I use the Option feature frequently as I am a software developer and need to use both Mac and Windows.

Everything else works perfectly. I can boot into any of the four bootable partitions using the System preferences (OS X) or Bootcamp options (Windows).

Ideas?  Suggestions?

Comment: Is it an actual Mac 5770 or a Windows one? I have exactly the same setup here & have never seen that issue.

Comment: I is purported to be a Mac version.  It was still in the static envelope and it booted perfectly the first time.  Is there a way to tell?  BTW, I did install it in slot 2. not slot 1 as the old graphics card was.

Comment: terrible photo [& ought to prompt me to get in there & do some dusting soon] but this is what mine looks like - http://i.imgur.com/Eo6euhE.jpg

Comment: btw, I've had mine in slots 1 & 4, but never tried 2 or 3 - no idea what difference it may make